# VB.NET Error in import Excel in datagrid view

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in a button to import excel (which I got online as well)

```
Imports System.Data
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop


Public Class Template

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlRange As Excel.Range
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim xlRow As Integer

    With OpenFileDialog1
            .Title = "Import Excel"
            .FileName = ""
            .Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx;*.xls"


         If .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                sFileName = .FileName

             If Trim(sFileName) <> "" Then

                 xlApp = New Excel.Application
                 xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFileName)
                 xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Template")
                 xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange

                 Dim rowcount As Integer = 17
                 For xlRow = 17 To xlRange.Rows.Count '//data starts at R17C1
                       
                     If xlRange.Cells(xlRow, 1).Text <> String.Empty Then
                        rowcount += 1
                        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowcount, xlRange.Cells(xlRow, 1).Text,
                                        xlRange.Cells(xlRow, 2).Text,
                                        xlRange.Cells(xlRow, 3).Text,
                                        xlRange.Cells(xlRow, 4).Text,
                                        xlRange.Cells(xlRow, 5).Text,
                                        xlRange.Cells(xlRow, 6).Text,
                                        xlRange.Cells(xlRow, 7).Text,
                                        xlRange.Cells(xlRow, 8).Text,
                                        xlRange.Cells(xlRow, 9).Text,
                                        xlRange.Cells(xlRow, 10).Text)

                     End If
                 Next
             End If
         End If
   End With

End Class
```

Now I am having an error `System.MissingMemberException`:

[image]

I am stuck for days and no solution has been found online. I tried using .ToString instead of .Text but it only I got System_.Comobject displayed in datagrid. I have the correct path and sheet name. Please help me solve this error. I am pretty new with .Net so guide and treat me as a beginner.

Comment: Replace all `.Text` with `.Value2` and try. Also, you should close `xlWorkBook` and quit `xlApp` when you done.

Comment: @dr.null Thank you for your remarks. I tried your suggestion, but error remains.

Comment: The following posts contain some [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia) code that may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72759270/10024425, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71755749/10024425, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72794540/10024425.

Comment: You've set xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange, then your loop is For xlRow = 17 To xlRange.Rows.Count.  Are you sure that xlRange has more than 17 rows?

Comment: @Hursey yes I am sure there are more than 17 rows, xlRow is = row number not the usedrange. Anyhow, I have already solved the issue. I have converted the row to string like this - DataGridView1.Rows.Add(xlRange.Range("A" & xlRow.ToString).Text, ....)

Comment: Could you answer your question and mark as accepted?  So others know your problem is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my question. I used the code below and it worked.

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(xlRange.Range("A" & xlRow.ToString).Text, ...)
```